# TeamCity with msunit: How to copy dll into output folder?

Tags: unit-testing, resources, teamcity

I want to run my (working) msunit tests with teamcity. Within my test, I need several files which I successfully copied using either one of the following ways (when running the tests from within VS):

1. file properties -> copy to output directory
2. or copying them using a post build step using xcopy

As post build actions I tried:

```
xcopy /Y "$(ProjectDir)*somelib*.dll" "$(TargetDir)"
```

or

```
xcopy /Y "$(ProjectDir)*somelib*.dll" "$(OutDir)"
```

As you can see, I have *somelib*.dll files that need to be copied. This is due to the usage of a library, which I listed as a reference. This lib is copied corretly, but it needs some older (c++) dlls, which are not included in the reference package.

Unfortunately I could not find a way to either get TeamCity to run the msunit test within the bin/debug/ folder, or to copy all neccessary files to the working temp folder.

(My goal is to run all unit tests from several test suites and to gather results from dotCover for all tests.)

What is a good way to deal with this situation? I noticed the possibility to pack files into the assembly as resources, and to unpack them inside the unit tests right before they are needed. I will need the dlls in every test and would like to keet it DRY - is this a wise way to "just" copy the files?

Answer (score 0):

As far as TeamCity is concerned, you can make sure the process works when run from the command line (n the TeamCity agent machine, in the same directory, [etc](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Common+Problems#CommonProblems-BuildfailsorbehavesdifferentlyinTeamCitybutnotlocally).) and then replicate the same steps in a TeamCity build. Since TeamCity just launches MSBuild as external process and executes the configured commands, there should be no TeamCity-specific peculiarities.